# NSDateFormatter not returning proper date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

All,

I have an `NSDateFormatter`, and it doesn't seem to be returning the proper month. Below is my code:

```
- (NSDate *)stringToDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];

    return [df dateFromString:self];
}

+ (NSString *)dateToString:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM DD, YYYY"];

    return [df stringFromDate:date];
}

+ (NSString *)formatLongDate:(NSString *)string
{
    NSDate *date = [string stringToDate];

    return [NSString dateToString:date];
}
```

When I pass in `[NSString formatLongDate:@"2013-10-09"]`, the result is **January 9, 2013** instead of **October 9, 2013**. I'm lost as to why this might be happening. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Just as a thought, try using `yyyy` and `dd` instead of `YYYY` and `DD`.

Comment: -1 for not taking the time to lookup the proper format specifiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that `DD` is "day of year" rather than "day of month" - and `YYYY` is a "week year" rather than just "year". (Week years are odd, basically. Best to just ignore them if possible :)

So try formats of "yyyy-MM-dd" and "MMMM dd, yyyy" instead. It's important to be *absolutely precise* in the format strings, including casing. When in doubt, check! Follow the links on the [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4) page (the exact Unicode Technical Standard version used depends on the version of iOS you're using) for details.

Comment: Indeed! see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @Taum: Yes, I didn't want to link to a specific version as different iOS versions use different ones - but I'll link to the page that links to them :)

Comment: @JonSkeet to the rescue again. Thanks for pointing that out...it was a bit careless on my part.

Comment: @workInAFishBowl: It's *very* easily done - particularly with YYYY, which will give you the same value as yyyy *most* of the time.